# Carousel in Bot Framework - continuously updating from database - upon scrolling it?

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-bot-service

Is it possible that carousel in Bot Framework (where it is allowed - like Messenger, Bot Emulator etc.) updates continuously (according to a database from which it reads data) after it was initially rendered and sent as a message to the user - without rerendering the whole carousel and resending it to the user?

Something like - .onFlipHandRightOnCarousel or .onFlipHandLeftOnCarousel - delete void HeroCards (where in database they are flagged as 'inactive') from already rendered carousel and rerender this new carousel without resending a new session.send(msg) to the user?

Answer (score 0):

Modifying messages that have already been sent means modifying the chat history. This functionality will be highly channel-specific as it depends on how the client handles the history and what the client allows users to do to the history. Many channels do not support this functionality but some do. Generally speaking, if you as a user can go back and delete or edit messages in the chat history then a bot can too. If you as a user cannot then you should not expect a bot to be able to do it. But if you're working with a channel that does allow history edits then I imagine you should be able to edit the carousels if those are also supported.

Comment: Thanks, Kyle, it's a good hint about the channel-specific functionality to modify messages, I'll search it further...

Comment: If this answers your question, don't forget to vote it up and mark it as correct